# isDirty is always false when having react-hook-form, forwardRef, and react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am a student who is new to React. I currently try to build a form using `yup`, `react-hook-form`, `styled-components`, and `react-router-dom` for navigating and switching between sites.
The problem is the when I try to test if the input field is blank, or back to blank input when user erases the input field, `formState.touchedFields` are working, except for `isDirty` and `dirtyFields` continuing being **blank** or **false**. This problem only occurs when trying to use `isDirty`, and `dirtyFields` with the custom Input component that has `forwardRef`.

When submitting, the console log still prints the useForm's `data`. Also, when accessing the `touchedFields` in the `formState`, it still prints if the user has touched the input. However, when printing `isDirty`, or `dirtyFields`, it keeps being **false** or **empty object**.

```js
const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <input ref={ref} {...props} />
));
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().required('Username is required')
});
```

```js
const LoginForm = () => {
  const defaultValues = { username: '' };
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isDirty, touchedFields } } = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data); // working
    console.log(touchedFields); // working
    console.log(isDirty); // always being False despite inputting input
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        {...register('username')}
      />
      <button type="submit" disabled={!formState.isDirty}>
        Login
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

However, if I try with simple input (not using custom Input), the `isDirty` works normally.

```js
<input {...register('username')} />
```

I also try fixing the same as [***How to share ref usage?***](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs/) in the ***reat-hook-form*** documentation, but it gives me error

```js
const Input = forwardRef((props, ref, register, registerName) => (
  <input ref={(event) => {
        register(registerName).ref(event);
        ref.current = event;} } {...props} />
));
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().required('Username is required')
});
```

```js
  <input ref={ref} register={register} registerName="username" {...props} />
```

```
react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'current')
    at ref (Input.jsx:65:13)
    at commitAttachRef (react-dom.development.js:23645:20)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23503:9)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:9)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26117:3)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12042:22)
```

```
The above error occurred in the <input> component:

    at input
    at O2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=cb867138:1155:6)
    at Input2 (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Input/Input.jsx?t=1672837406977:23:3)
    at form
    at O2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=cb867138:1155:6)
    at TweetInput (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Sections/TweetSection/TweetInput.jsx?t=1672837406977:26:6)
    at div
    at O2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=cb867138:1155:6)
    at Home (http://localhost:5173/src/pages/Home.jsx?t=1672837406977:28:6)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=cb867138:2707:5)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=cb867138:2972:26)
    at div
    at VisualElementHandler (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/framer-motion.js?v=cb867138:273:28)
    at MotionComponent (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/framer-motion.js?v=cb867138:299:40)
    at O2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=cb867138:1155:6)
    at Main (http://localhost:5173/src/pages/Main.jsx?t=1672828435928:41:3)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=cb867138:2707:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=cb867138:3032:5)
    at PresenceChild (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/framer-motion.js?v=cb867138:6253:24)
    at AnimatePresence (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/framer-motion.js?v=cb867138:6308:26)
    at Fe (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=cb867138:1110:40)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx?t=1672837406977:39:33)
    at PersistGate2 (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/redux-persist_integration_react.js?v=cb867138:90:5)
    at Provider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-redux.js?v=cb867138:823:3)
    at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-RMCMWTPY.js?v=cb867138:2624:3)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=cb867138:2979:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=cb867138:3390:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

May I ask what's the problem?

Comment: You should show what code results in the error

Comment: Works fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-allen-czhkb7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have just added error message. The code results show nothing on screen. I wonder if it is because of having react-router-dom in outside.

Comment: This is not how you use `forwardRef` here - `forwardRef((props, ref, register, registerName)`. Also, please open the link I posted. I copied your code (expect yup) and it works

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have just compared it with my code. I found I accidentally put `onChange` function to be `null`, and pass it to props; therefore, it affects how `isDirty` works. Anyway thank you very much.